# Integration over a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Let $S$ be given by

$$S= \left[(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}\;|\; x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz=\frac12 \right]$$

and  $$\omega = xdy \wedge dz\, -\, \frac {2z}{y^3} \, dx\wedge dy \,+\, \frac1{y^2}dz\wedge dx $$

Explain how to give an orientation for $S$ and compute $\int_S \omega$ with respect to that orientation.

I know it involves Stokes's theorem and that $d\omega = dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ but I'm kind lost about the orientation and actually computing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in fact $\mathrm{d}\omega = dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ then by Stokes' Theorem, you are computing the volume of the region enclosed by $S$.  This region happens to be an ellipsoid, tilted with respect to the given axes.  You can figure out how to obtain the dimensions and orientation of the axes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Generalised_equations).  It turns out that this ellipsoid has semiaxes of length $1$, $1$, and $1/2$, so the volume of the ellipsoid is $2\pi/3$, and the value of the integral is $(2\pi/3) dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$.

That said, I am not so sure that $\mathrm{d}\omega = dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ as you state, because the 2-forms are in cyclic order and will not change sign upon differentiation.  In that case, the terms with $y$ will not cancel.  The resulting integral, however, would be a mess and if this is homework, I'd be surprised if that was the intention.

Comment: I think it's fine, unless I messed up somewhere while computing $d\omega$, thank you for your answer in any case.

Comment: I was just checking something... isn't the volume $\frac23 \pi$?

Comment: Unless my numbers were off, I got $\pi/2$ based on the volume being $\pi$ times the product of the semi-axes.  The semi-axes are the square root of the eigenvalues of the inverse of the coefficient matrix (see the link I provided), and my calculations provided semi-axes of $1$, $1$, and $1/2$.

Comment: Yeah, I agree about the semiaxes, but isn't the volume what you said times $\frac43$?

Comment: Oh man, you are right - how humbling.  Of course there's a 4/3 factor!  I will fix in the solution.

Comment: No problem at all, the most important parts were there. This was just a small formula mistake. Once again thank you!